# Google chart gauge is not displayed, TypeError: google.visualization.Gauge is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have included 2 charts in my page one is bar chart and gauge chart using google chart. The bar chart displayed perfectly but not matter how I tweaked the code the 'gauge' chart wont be displayed.

these are the javascript that I included

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=myFunc" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

here is the java script code to display the chart. I am taking the data from the database to be displayed.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    // Global variable to hold data
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: 'pageUtamaDataEntry.aspx/GetChartData',
            data: '{}',
            success:
                function (response) {
                    drawchart(response.d);
                },

            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
            }
        });
    })

    function drawchart(dataValues) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'BranchName');
        data.addColumn('number', 'TotalDelivery');


        data.addRow([dataValues[0].BranchName, 
        dataValues[0].TotalDelivery]);

        var barchart_options = { title: 'Rekapitulasi Pendapatan tahun berjalan',
            vAxis: { title: 'BranchName' },
            hAxis: { title: 'TotalDelivery' },
            width: 550,
            height: 400,
            legend: 'none',
            seriesType: 'bars',
            series: { 5: { type: 'line'} }
        };
        var barchart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('barchart_div'));
        barchart.draw(data, barchart_options);


        var gauge_options= { title: 'whatsoever',
        width: 400, height: 120,
        redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
        yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
        minorTicks: 5
        };

        var gaugechart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        gaugechart.draw(data, gauge_options);

        setInterval(function () {
            data.setValue(0, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 13000);
        setInterval(function () {
            data.setValue(1, 1, 40 + Math.round(60 * Math.random()));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 5000);
        setInterval(function () {
            data.setValue(2, 1, 60 + Math.round(20 * Math.random()));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }, 26000);

    }

</script>
```

when I debug the javascript it says

> Uncaught TypeError: google.visualization.Gauge is not a constructor

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load gauge chart type before using it. Change the following line

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
```

to

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'gauge'] });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply, It works now I can sleep tight.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted